# How to stop character from moving after collision?

Tags: python, pygame, game-physics

I'm creating my own game in python, and I am trying to get my character to not move through the walls when he collides with them.

I've tried making the character's x velocity and y velocity 0, but that doesn't seem to work. I've seen people do this using object-oriented programming, is there any way to not use OOP?

```
# character co-ordinates
gokuX = 0
gokuY = 0

# using arrow keys to move the character
if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
    gokuVx = -RUN_SPEED
elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
    gokuVx = RUN_SPEED
if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
    gokuVy = -RUN_SPEED
elif keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
    gokuVy = RUN_SPEED

# the rectangle around my character
gokuRect = pygame.Rect(gokuX, gokuY, gokuW, gokuH)

# store the rectangles inside a list
lvl1rlist = [lvl1r0, lvl1r1, lvl1r2, lvl1r3, lvl1r4, lvl1r5, lvl1r6, 
lvl1r7, lvl1r8]

# detecting collisions between the character and the rectangles
for i in range(9):
    if gokuRect.colliderect(lvl1rlist[i]):
        # I don't know what to do here to make the character not move
```

I want my character to not be able to move past the walls, but still be able to move freely when not colliding with them

Comment: Why don't use want to use an object-oriented program? You might be better off doing so.

Comment: What is it that makes characters move? Seems like you need some way of disabling that, whatever it is Unfortunately there isn't enough code in your question for us to be able to tell you what would need to be done.

Comment: You need to invert the velocity instead of setting to zero. What you are trying to do is called [collision resolution](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/5906/collision-resolution). It's universal and fairly documented topic, so I'd like to leave the detail to the linked answers.

Comment: *is there any way to not use OOP* that's a stange requirement, since you basically can't use pygame without OOP. Even in the small code sample you posted you already use OOP.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your partial code, I'm assuming you need to re-arrange your functionalities - you only want to "move" your characters rectangle IF there is no collision - so the collision test needs to be done before you move, or right after (in which case you will need to reverse the previous movement - see alternative 2).

Alternative 1:

Logically: check for a collision; if no collision since last move, move the character.

```
    collision_detected = False

    # detecting collisions between the character and the rectangles after the last movement (!)
    for i in range(9):
        if gokuRect.colliderect(lvl1rlist[i]):
            print("collision detected.")       
            collision_detected  = True
            RUN_SPEED = 0
            # Show "Game Over" Screen



     if not collision_detected: 
        if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            gokuVx = -RUN_SPEED
        elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            gokuVx = RUN_SPEED
        if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
            gokuVy = -RUN_SPEED
        elif keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
            gokuVy = RUN_SPEED     


    # the rectangle around my character
    gokuRect = pygame.Rect(gokuX, gokuY, gokuW, gokuH)
```

Alternative 2: (reversing the movement - so the character is not "in" a wall, but is stopped right in front of it)

Logically: move character; check for collision; if there is a collision reverse last movement and show "Game Over" Screen

```
# movecharacter
if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
     gokuVx = -RUN_SPEED
elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
     gokuVx = RUN_SPEED
if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
     gokuVy = -RUN_SPEED
elif keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
     okuVy = RUN_SPEED

 # the rectangle around my character
gokuRect = pygame.Rect(gokuX, gokuY, gokuW, gokuH)


# check for a collision         
for i in range(9):
       if gokuRect.colliderect(lvl1rlist[i]):
           print("collision detected.")

            # reverse previous movement which has led to a collision  
           if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
               gokuVx = +RUN_SPEED
           elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
                gokuVx = RUN_SPEED
           if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
               gokuVy = +RUN_SPEED
           elif keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
               okuVy = RUN_SPEED

           RUN_SPEED = 0
           # Show "Game Over" Screen
```